# Getting apt to give running process status

Tags: apt

Since upgrading Debian `apt upgrade` is giving me a nice status report no processes that are running and still using old packages. This is very useful.

I would like to know how I can re-run this status check; after trying to restart some processes, I want to so how successful I was.

I can't find it in the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to figure out what’s providing this output for you by looking at any hooks defined in the `apt` configuration (look under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`). One package which implements this is [`whatmaps`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/whatmaps); it can even be configured to automatically restart services after security updates.

Unfortunately `whatmaps` is difficult to use outside `apt` when you’re looking for all processes which need to be restarted. Instead, I use `checkrestart` from [the `debian-goodies` package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/debian-goodies).

In your case, the package involved is [`needrestart`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/needrestart), and you can run the restart check directly:

```
sudo needrestart
```